# аналог foreach из php в Питоне для словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Доброго времени! Помогите разобраться созданием функции, функция принимает 2 параметра массив и значение число или строку, и должна перебрать всесь массив установив все его элементы как 0 но если ключ массива совпадает со вторым параметром функции то его выставить как 1 после чего вернуть перебранный массив, но если в php есть foreach для перебора массива, в питоне же не могу найти понятного аналога делаю вот так:

```
 def refarray(arr, key):

    #перебор массива
    if arr[curentkey] == key: 
          arr[curentkey] = 1;
    else:
          arr[curentkey] = 0;
      return res
```

Comment: Массива или словаря? Если массивы в привычном понимании с индексами, а если ассоциативные массивы, их еще словарями называют

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе, можно без модуля `copy` обойтись и сделать новый словарь через литерал:

```
def re_array(arr, check_key):
    return {key: int(key == check_key) for key in arr}


arr = {"apple": 123, "juice": 456}    
data = re_array(arr, "apple")
print(data)  # {'apple': 1, 'juice': 0}
print(arr)  # {'apple': 123, 'juice': 456}
```

Answer (score 3):

`foreach` в Python это стандартный `for`. Также, если тебе необходимо вернуть изменённую копию исходного массива, не затрагивая оригинальный массив, то насколько я знаю его для начала необходимо скопировать.

```
import copy

arr = {"apple":123,"juice":456}

def refarray(arr, key):
    res = copy.copy(arr)

    # Перебор словаря
    for i in res:
        if i == key: 
            res[i] = 1
        else:
            res[i] = 0

     return res

data = refarray(arr,"apple")
print(data)
print(arr)
```

Результат:

```
{'apple': 1, 'juice': 0}
{'apple': 123, 'juice': 456}
```

Comment: 1. `;` не нужны в питоне, 2. тело в цикле можно до одной строки сократить: `res[i] = 1 if i == key else 0`

Comment: @gil9red, или так `res[i] = int(i == key)`

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за замечание, при переносе кода опечатался